# How to deploy DACPAC file to sql azure using VSTS (Visual studio team services) Release Management

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ms-release-management, dacpac, azure-devops

I'm having a hard time figuring how to deploy a dacpac to sql azure using VSTS release management features. Most of the tutorial / videos I seen use a task called "Sql Azure DACPAC Deployment" I do not see that in my VSTS instance.

Comment: Is this what they are now calling SQL Database? Anyway, I see **Azure SQL Database Deployment - Deploy Azure SQL DACPAC**. Could that work for you?

Comment: I do not see this option

Answer (score 3):

The SQL Azure deployment task is not publicly released yet. It will be enabled in all accounts in a couple of weeks.